# IIS Express still running the project after project execution stop in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

Whenever I run a project from Visual Studio and stop running it, I can still request pages, get Data from the Database, add data to it. It's basically working absolutely fine like the project is still running. Also the project has not been published to the localhost and this is not the case only with one specific project it's happening with every project I run from my PC. Why is this happening?

Comment: even you stop your debugging in visual studio, it doesn't mean that the iis express also stop. with that, you can still access your site.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch Well normally it would stop, and you wouldn't be able to interact with the project unless you run the project again. Anyway do you know how to force it to stop once the project execution has stopped?

Comment: Right click your project > click Properties > select the 'Web' tab on the left > uncheck the Enable Edit and Continue checkbox. Make sure to check it.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I am using Visual Studio 2015 and there is not any check box even with a similar name on the Web tab.

Comment: It seems a open bug with vs2015 ->https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/2281270/iis-express-continues-running-after-debugging-session-ends

Comment: @Dr.Stitch Ye it does, thanks.